# Setting string name in main function only using getName

Tags: c++, string, class, constructor, polymorphism

I am working on an assignment using sub classes demonstrating polymorphism. This program requires a name to be given for each of the new objects. I am only supposed to have **string getName(){return name;}** (this is located in the base class). There is also a constructor in each of the classes **class(string){}**. In the main function I want to set the name for each of the objects. Any advice is much appreciated in how I should do so!

h file:

```
#ifndef DUCK_H
#define DUCK_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Duck
{
private:
    string name;
public:
    Duck(){}
    Duck(string){}
    string getName() { return name; };
    virtual string quack() {return "Which"; }
    virtual string fly() { return "How?"; }
};
class RubberDuck : public Duck
{
public:
    RubberDuck(){}
    RubberDuck(string) {}
    string quack() { return "Squeak"; }
    string fly() { return "Fly with bounce"; }
};
class MallardDuck : public Duck
{
public:
    MallardDuck(){}
    MallardDuck(string) {}
    string quack() { return "Quack"; }
    string fly() { return "Fly with wings"; }
};
class RocketDuck : public Duck
{
public:
    RocketDuck(){}
    RocketDuck(string) {}
    string quack() { return "Zoom"; }
    string fly() { return "Fly with rockets"; }
};
#endif // !1
```

cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Duck.h"
using namespace std;

//void display(Duck *d);

int main()
{
    Duck d1;
    MallardDuck md;
    RubberDuck rbd;
    RocketDuck rd;

    //for main duck
    //Duck duck("Donald");
    //cout << duck.getName();
    cout << d1.quack() <<"\n";
    cout << d1.fly() <<"\n";
    cout << "\n";
    //for rubber duck
    RubberDuck rbdname("Rubby");
    cout << rbd.quack() << "\n";
    cout << rbd.fly() << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    //for mallard duck
    MallardDuck mdname("Mally");
    cout << md.quack() << "\n";
    cout << md.fly() << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    // for rocket duck
    RocketDuck rdname("Rocky");
    cout << rd.quack() << "\n";
    cout << rd.fly() << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    //polymorphism
    Duck *d2 = new MallardDuck();
    cout << d2->getName() << "\n";
    cout << d2->quack() << "\n";
    cout << d2->fly() << "\n";
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
 }
/*void display(Duck d)
{
    cout << d.quack();
}
*/
```

Comment: Show some code.  (`class(string){}` is not code.)

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: So... what do you need help with? The constructor? The virtual functions?

Comment: @Beta I have all that. What I want to do is set a name for each of the Ducks. I don't need setName because these names will be by default. I want to do this in the main function.

Comment: `Duck D; D.name = "Donald";` What's the problem?

Comment: @Beta calling name in the main function like that is impossible. "name" is a private member.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I'm accustomed to putting the public members on top, and misread. You'll have to use the constructor or a setter (or do something perverse).

Comment: Don't worry about it. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to call the constructor you've defined?  You would do that like

```
Duck duck("Drake Mallard");
```

Comment: Doing that does not display "Drake Mallard". I want to set the name in main function to display when it compiles.

Comment: @NacDan `Duck::Duck(string const & input_name) : name(input_name) {}`

Comment: @O'Neil I do not understand. Is this a constructor that I put in the class? Also what is input_name? Say i want Duck to be named "Donald" how would I set it?

Comment: @NacDan Yes it's a constructor, and this is the proper way to initialize your member `name` with the value of the parameter `input_name` = `"Drake Mallard"` in aschepler's code.

Comment: @O'Neil if I am understanding correctly, I replace the original constructor containing string with this: Duck::Duck(string const &Donald) : name("Donald") {}
I have 3 sub classes I want to separately define names for. I was trying to do 
Duck duck("Donald");
cout << "Name: " << duck.getName() << endl; but it is not displaying Donald.

Comment: @NacDan 3 classes, or instances? Please edit your original message to update your code.

Comment: @O'Neil I updated the code. I want to set names for each of the ducks in the main function.

Comment: @NacDan See my answer

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
    Duck(){}
    Duck(string){}
```

You don't initialize your member `name`, whether you call the default constructor or the `string` one.
You **have to** use the input parameter like I showed you:

```
Duck(string const & input_name) : name(input_name) {}
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The underlined part initializes your member `name` to the value `"Drake Mallard"` when you do:

```
Duck duck("Drake Mallard");
```

Then, you will have `duck.getName()` returning `"Drake Mallard"`.

And you have to apply the same principle in your derived classes, to call this very same base constructor:

```
class RubberDuck : public Duck
{
 public:
    RubberDuck() : Duck("RubberDuck") {}
    RubberDuck(string const & input_name) : Duck(input_name) {}
```

Then

```
RubberDuck rubber;          // name = "RubberDuck"
RubberDuck rubber("Ruber"); // name = "Rubber"
```

But also:

```
RubberDuck * rubber = new RubberDuck();        // name = "RubberDuck"
RubberDuck * rubber = new RubberDuck("Ruber"); // name = "Rubber"
```

If you ask, the front part `Duck::` in my comment considered you where implementing your constructor outside of `class Duck { ... };`.

You should avoid `using namespace`, especially within headers.

Comment: Thanks O'Neil. Your help allowed me to find out how to do it in a similar way. I am using pointers that access getName. 
ex: Duck *rbdName = new RubberDuck();
cout << rbdName->getName() << "\n";